# Add event on slot

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to implement generic modal component with Vue 3.
And I want to close modal window on click outside the modal's content.
So I added 'close' event on modalWrapper and 'contentClick' to prevent closing (bubbling) when content is clicked:

```
contentClick(event:Event){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Modal:

```
<template>
<teleport to="body">
  <div class="modal-window" v-on:click="close" v-show="isOpened">
    <slot class="modal-window__content" v-on:click="contentClick($event)"></slot>
  </div>
</teleport>
</template>
```

The problem is that `contentClick(event:Event)` is not fired for some reason. I can wrap slot into another div and put contentClick event on it, but not sure that it's a good solution

Comment: `<slot>` isn't a DOM element. You can't set attributes and event listeners on it. If you don't want to use a wrapper element, you would have to bind the attributes and event listeners to the slot (like props) and the slot would be responsible for setting it on the root element.

Comment: @DecadeMoon thanks. So it's better to wrap it for me.

Comment: Is that `contentClick` event even needed? What about `@click.self` on the wrapper? [Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-modifiers)

Comment: @MichalLevý yep. it's even better, thanks